# Calculation of Horizontal Coordinates

Tags: fundamental-astronomy, coordinate

Given a fixed coordinate location on Earth (i.e. a latitude and longitude), and a fixed equatorial coordinate location of a particular astronomical object in the sky (i.e. right ascension and declination), how can I calculate the horizontal coordinates as a function of date and time on Earth?

Comment: http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8390/cancelling-out-earth-rotation-speed-altazimuth-mount/8415#8415 may help

Answer (score 4):

You can't, not with that information. However if you also have the date and time, you'll be good to go: there are plenty of sites in the web with this information, such as: [RA and DEC to ALT and AZ](http://www.stargazing.net/kepler/altaz.html)