# How do I get from Star Atlas to real life?

Tags: positional-astronomy

This question is about finding the elevation and bearing of a given star at a particular time at Latitude 52N.

I look up the RA and Declination of my star. How do I calculate its bearing and elevation at hourly intervals?

Comment: The RA of a star is pretty much fixed. Do you mean the *azimuth* and elevation? There are several websites that should help you convert RA/declination to azimuth/altitude, or I can give you the insanely complicated formula I gave for another answer.

Comment: I think the OP uses "Bearing", and by that means azimuth.The use of RA at the end looks like an error. Edited.... @barry could you  link that other answer?

Comment: http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8390/cancelling-out-earth-rotation-speed-altazimuth-mount/8415#8415

Answer (score 1):

The Right Ascension of a star is fixed (ignoring precession of the equinoxes). What you need or want to know is the "sidereal time" - that is to say the "time" based on which RA is at your local meridian at a given time. The sidereal day is slightly shorter than the mean solar day (ie the 24 hour day) and so sidereal and solar times drift apart - only being equivalent at the vernal equinox.

Comment: Also ignoring proper motion (which is negligible over moderate time scales).